# UI Freezes when AVPlayer play audio in background

Tags: swift, webview, avplayer

I have UIWebView, which is only created and url is loaded, but this WebView is not assign to any view. I am getting HTML content for every 5 seconds from UIWebView using Timer. This work fine till the time I am not playing audio in background. When audio is playing in background, get HTML content from UIWebView require some time and my UI is freezes for 4 to 5 seconds, and continuous call to get HTML cause application unresponsive.

UI get freeze when audio is playing in background and get HTML content form WebView. Not able to press even a button on screen.

I am using RadioKit library for playing audio.

1) I have tried AVPlayer play() on global queue.
2) Load WebView in AppDelegate.
3) Call WebView delegate methods - webViewDidFinishLoad() and get HTML there.
4) Get HTML content in AppDelegate, and notify after get HTML content.

```
let webView = UIWebView() 

//Load URL request.

    if let url = URL(string: "Some string here") {
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            self.webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)

        } 

   webView.delegate = self

//WebView Delegate

     func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        self.loadWebpageTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.loadWebPage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

//loadWebPage

     @objc func loadWebPage(){

     DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.interfaceType = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('Interface_Type').value")

     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("WebViewUpdate"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)

}

//In Other view for update the UI add observer
```

UI get freeze when audio is playing in background and get HTML content form WebView. I want my UI not Freezes while I get HTML form WebView.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using UIWebView it's deprecated use WKWebView ? Did you try playing audio on bg queue?